# How to check authority of sensitive requests between two nodes in cluster?

Tags: authorization

Assume we have a platform which has some crypto functionalities.
the infrastructure is as follows:

- We have two nodes in a cluster, Computer A and Computer B.
- Computer A is the main server which handles many types of requests from clients including withdrawal requests.
- Computer B is responsible for accepting withdrawal requests, ex: send x amount to y address.
- Computer A has a public IP address but computer B doesn't have, both connected within a local network.
- The connection between them is secured using SSL/TLS.

When a user submits a withdrawal request to Computer A, then the main server verifies and validates the balance and destination and then asks Computer B to transfer the amount.

If a user hacks into Computer A, then he can send a fake request to Computer B to transfer x amount to y address.

How can we verify the authority of the request to ensure the balance and destination are valid, which are always validated in app in Computer A, but we cannot verify it if the request is sent by the hacker?

Computer B doesn't have access to resources in Computer A nor anything on the internet.

Are there any standard methods to handle such a situation?

Comment: Please format your posts for readability. this was very difficult to undersdtand.

Comment: The answer is simple: send an authorization code/password along with the request to Computer B. But I'm guessing there is more context and more facts than this that you haven't disclosed. Because all you've asked is: how does Computer B validate the request from Computer A? And that's a solved problem.

Comment: *"How can we verify the authority of the request"* - how does computer A checks the authority of the clients request? Could this be reused for validating the requests by B?

Comment: This is basically an endpoint security problem.  If an attacker breaches computer A and manages to elevate his privilege to at least the level of privilege that the application has, then the attacker can do anything that the application can do.  This includes creating requests to computer B, the same way that the application would.  Even a protocol where requests are signed by an HSM will not mitigate this type of attack, as the attacker can simply cause the HSM to sign a request the same way that the application would.  In most systems, once the endpoint is breached, it's usually game over.

Comment: @mti2935 is there any standards I can search about to gain better security?

Comment: @user3840019 The typical measures for securing a server would apply - e.g. use a firewall to close off all unused ports, stay current with updates, and harden all services running on any exposed ports as much as possible.